# gmail REST api 'import message' with python requests

Tags: python-2.7, import, python-requests, gmail-api, eml

I am trying to upload an email to gmail account using gmail REST API for import message https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/import#http-request using python requests module. email is in RAW format (i.e. data of .eml file encoded with base64.b64encode()) with body

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/import
{
 "raw": ".........."
}
```

This is working for RAW data size up to few MBs (say 5MB), but I am getting '**Connection Timeout**' error if i try to upload bigger data (**~10 MB** or more).

Can anybody tell me the way to upload bigger email data using this API.

I am using OAuth access_token to call these APIs

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the **`uploadType`** to **`resumable`**

## [Resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#resumable)

> To upload data files more reliably, you can use the resumable upload protocol. This protocol allows you to resume an upload operation after a communication failure has interrupted the flow of data. It is especially useful if you are *transferring large files* and the likelihood of a *network interruption* or some other *transmission failure is high*, for example, when uploading from a mobile client app. It can also reduce your bandwidth usage in the event of network failures because you don't have to restart large file uploads from the beginning.

Example: Resumable session initiation request

```
POST /upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send?uploadType=resumable HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token
Content-Length: 38
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Upload-Content-Type: message/rfc822
X-Upload-Content-Length: 2000000

{
"id": string,
"threadId": string,
"labelIds": [
string
],
"snippet": string,
"historyId": unsigned long,
"payload": {
"partId": string,
"mimeType": string,
"filename": string,
"headers": [
{
"name": string,
"value": string
}
],
"body": users.messages.attachments Resource,
"parts": [
(MessagePart)
]
},
"sizeEstimate": integer,
"raw": bytes
}
```

Comment: @mr-rebot
Thanks for the example, I am not trying to send mail but trying to restore/import existing mail with RAW eml stream.
While importing using /upload and uploadType=resumable), I am getting error as 
{u'error': {u'code': 400, u'message': u"Expected a single 'From' header", u'errors': [{u'domain': u'global', u'message': u"Expected a single 'From' header", u'reason': u'invalidArgument'}]}}

Comment: @mr-rebot,  I have tried this example (send mail). It is returning me empty response with status code 200. I am expecting response like below but getting empty. i.e. no location/session_uri in response.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Location: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=xa298sd_sdlkj2
Content-Length: 0